# Broken Download Files

Tags: networking, 18.04, 17.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and I got some problem with download large file from the Internet (some time with small files). All ways get broken package when extract/open these file, with how many times download I get different SHA checksum value

I have tried.

1. Use **Chrome/Firefox/Opera** to download files.
2. Use **curl/wget** to download files.
3. Reinstall Ubuntu
4. Switch Network Eth/Wifi
5. Check with another computer (file download completed, SHA validated)
6. Set hardcode DNS server/Static IP.
7. Use **Uget** to download these file.
8. Use torrent download I mush recheck and redownload many times to get right SHA checksum value.

My Computer Info: 
 MSI, NVIDIA Graphic.

Thank any tips.

Comment: Broken how? truncated? Or correct size but invalid content? Where are the downloaded files? HDD? SSD? temp filesystem in RAM?

Comment: Correct Size but invalid content, HDD & SSD are the same.

Comment: Other things to try: 1) try with a different distro (live USB) (very different from Ubuntu, so Fedora...), 2) run a memory check 3) if you still have a clean and a corrupt copy of some file, how much is corrupt? Just a 4K block, or most of the file?

Comment: Just some block of the file. I think that some issue with net work package because some time i get error when pull git responsitory.

Comment: So far we cannot dismiss hardware problems. If there were network problems in 18.04 you would have plenty of hits in your fave search engine.  So IMHO either you have some rather common hardware and it's defective, or you have some exotic hardware and the network drivers are buggy. Running a different OS or at least distro would help pinpointing the problem.

Comment: @xenoid thank verry much, I have install prevert ubuntu version 16.10 just waiting for stable newest ubuntu version